# My cilantro plant is dying

Tags: watering, cilantro

So I over watered my cilantro not realizing I was doing so. I live in Houston, TX and it’s currently 95+ degrees and getting hotter. I thought with the heat it needed that much water. I was wrong. What can I do to save it?[image]